# JavaScript div height after list results are updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I currently have some javascript code to make sure that all of the divs are the same size irrespective of the amount of text / pictures inside it.

```
window.onload = function() {
    boxes = $('.albums');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
        Math, boxes.map(function() {
            return $(this).height();
        }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
};
```

That works for me but I'm trying to implement it using the filteriffic gem which is a rails plugin to filter, search, and sort ActiveRecord lists.

The list changes as a user types in a keyword. Once they have finished typing the divs are now not the same size so they don't fit into the same row and the layout is out of sync.

How do I modify my javascript code so that it is re-run every time the list is updated?

Comment: Make it a function, and trigger it when an event is triggered. Does the filteriffic have any events??

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking this function into the `change` event.

```
$('#filterrific_filter').on('change', function(){
    boxes = $('.albums');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
        Math, boxes.map(function() {
            return $(this).height();
        }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: Tried adding that it but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Could it be because it hasn't waited for all of the boxes to load before making the adjustment?

Comment: I woud add a `console.log(boxes)` to see what's inside when the max is computed.